# MySQL Split to use in "SELECT WHERE IN" statement

Tags: c#, sql, mysql, csv

I've been scouring various MySQL sites in the hope of finding something that will allow me to turn this:

```
var parameters = "a,b,c,d"; // (Could be any number of comma-delimited values)
```

Into this (assuming that my parameters are somehow becoming the values you see in the IN block):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE parametertype IN('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

But I'm not having a great deal of success!  The best site I've found has been: [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html), which discusses the splitting of strings based on a delimiter (',' in my case) although it hasn't turned up any answers...

Does anyone know of a good way of splitting a comma-delimited string into a group of strings that can be used in this context?

Comment: you want to split string by means of mysql or by means of c#?

Comment: Hi TGadfly, I'll be passing something like "'a','b','c'" into SQL from C# in order to use IN('a','b','c') but of course (sod's law) that doesn't work!  Thanks for your correspondence!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not have all the flexibility you need, but the MySQL [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function might be sufficient.
There's a hard limit of a maximum of 64 values in the set to compare with though.

For example:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET( parametertype, 'a,b,c,d' ) != 0
```

This is an example of the use of an in-line MySQL [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html) ('a,b,c,d') - its sort-of an enum.  It *may* be a sign that something is awry with the normalisation of the data model if these are being used.  But, they can be handy to eliminate a join, or (as in this case) to associate with complex information that resides outside the database.

Comment: Superb answer Martin!  I was trying to apply a WHERE clause and getting myself in a right mess figuring out why it wasn't working!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic sql

```
delimiter //; 
create procedure tst() 
begin 
prepare stmp from 'INSERT INTO LOGG SELECT PFILE_Filename FROM PFILE_FILE'; 
execute stmp; 
deallocate prepare stmp; 
end// 
delimiter ;//
```

you have to do something like this

you have a part of sql query

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE parametertype IN(
```

then you join it with a string passed as a parameter "'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'" using CONCAT function
for example into stmp as above and then execute stmp

Comment: TGadfly, what is this PFILE?  Sorry to pester you!

Comment: IT was just an example of executing string as an sql
you can create this string dynamically
if you pass string 'a','b' as a parameter mysql recognizes it as a string, but if you join it with another string end then call execute your_string_name it will be recognized as an array of parameters

Comment: Doesn't this leave me open to SQL-Injection?

Comment: any way it will. use some filtering